# export complete database from Microsft Azure to .CSV or .TXT or .XLS or .XML etc

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to download my complete database that is stored on a microsft azure cloud system but I do not know how to do it. Could any one please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this is probably a pretty simple question to answer, as it stands it is unclear as to what you are asking.  Can I ask you to read "[ask]" and [edit] your question to include as much information as possible, for example, is your database stored in SQL Azure or SQL Server on a VM? How large is your database and what is your goal once you have exported the data.

Comment: is the DB on SQL Azure or a 'normal' database in a VM? If it's SQL Azure you can just export (creates a .bacpac) then deal with the transformation to csv or whatever locally

Comment: @NeilThompson How to convert bacpac to csv?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use SQL Server Management Studio Data Export capability.

1) [Download SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

2) Connect to your database (you may find the connection string on the DB dashboard)

3) Right click on your database in SSMS and choose Tasks -> Export Data

4) Complete the wizard. In destination part you may choose "Flat File Destination".

That should get you the data in the, for example, CSV format.